# Convert rows to columns by same column value in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table like:

```
id     name    value
--------------------
1      x       100
1      y       200
1      z       300
2      x       10
2      y       abc
2      z       001
3      x       1
...
--------------------
```

and I need to transform it into something like that:

```
id    x     y     z
---------------------
1     100   200   300
2     10    abc   001
3     1     ...
---------------------
```

Names are determined. I could make multiple joins but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation which in Postgres uses the `filter` syntax:

```
select id,
       max(value) filter (where name = 'x') as x,
       max(value) filter (where name = 'y') as y,
       max(value) filter (where name = 'z') as z
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: is it possible to make it dynamic? for example for bigger input  the entire alphabet  (a..z).
without writing  26 rows max(value )... ?
@gordon-linoff

Comment: @ilia … You could aggregate by the first letter (and id)

Answer (score 1):

The additional module [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) provides variants of the `crosstab()`  function, which is typically fastest:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT id, name, value
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1, 2'
   ) AS ct (id int, x text, y text, z text);
```

You seem to have a mix of numbers and strings in your `value`, so I chose `text` as output.

See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)